# how to update my notification when new row is inserted to notifications table

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, database

I have a page with a notification area where notification comes.(like facebook)

Now what i want is when a new row is inserted into database i want to alert user with a message (or increment numbers under notification icon).

I don't want to run ajax on set interval and check if new notification exists or not

is there any way to check notification only when new record is inserted into notifications table?

Comment: Look at node.js - it might do what you want.

Comment: you need a bi-directional connection, HTTP protocol is not designed for that , you need to use **web-sockets** if you don't want to check the server periodically with an AJAX